# Replace each line containing a specific word from the first file with the line from the second file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two txt files, the first one contains duplicated word "PACKAGES", i want to replace each "PACKAGES" word with a line from file 2

Ex of file 1:

```
NEW FUSTAT TOURS
City
USA
Address
napolean
PACKAGES
Test TOURS
City
UK
Address
napolean
PACKAGES
```

Ex of file 2:

```
First Company
Second Company
```

Expected Output:

```
NEW FUSTAT TOURS
City
USA
Address
napolean
First Company
Test TOURS
City
UK
Address
napolean
Second Company
```

I tried:

```
with open("file1.txt", encoding="utf-8") as first, open("file2.txt", encoding="utf-8") as second:
        first_file = first.read()
        second_file = second.readline()
        print(first_file.replace('PACKAGES', second_file))
```

Result:

```
NEW FUSTAT TOURS
City
USA
Addres
napolean
Phone Number
************
Email
***************
First Company
Test TOURS
City
UK
Addres
napolean
Phone Number
************
Email
***************
First Company
```

Any kind of help please?

Comment: What happens when the first file contains more occurrences of PACKAGES than there are lines in file2.txt ?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Two files always the same occurrences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
with open('file1.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f1:
    with open('file2.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f2:
        f2lines = iter(f2.readlines())
        for f1line in f1:
            if f1line.startswith('PACKAGES'):
                print(next(f2lines), end='')
            else:
                print(f1line, end='')
```

**Output:**

```
NEW FUSTAT TOURS
City
USA
Address
napolean
First Company
Test TOURS
City
UK
Address
napolean
Second Company
```